# Mapstruct expression mappings using multiple source parameters

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, mapstruct

I am trying to map two fields to a single object, where the relevant fields are list objects and the said object cannot be changed.

```java
@Mapping(target = "myWrapperObject.myListObject", 
         expression = "java(myListMap.get(keyParent.getKey()))")
@Mapping(target = "myOtherObject", 
         expression = "java(myOtherClassList.add(myOtherObject))")
MyFinalClass mapStuff(Map<String, List<MyClass>> myListMap, MyOtherClass keyParent);
```

If I try this and do a build, I get something like

```
[ERROR]/path/to/my/mapperImpl.java: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable myListMap
[ERROR]/path/to/my/mapperImpl.java: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable keyParent
```

This makes no sense since both of those symbols are passed in parameters and I would think they would be recognized. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you share how the generated `mapperImpl.java` looks like and also the actual `mapper.java` file as well.

Looking at the mapper method I don't see how MapStruct can even generate something. You are mapping using a `Map` into an object

Comment: The `Map` class is not really relevant in this situation. From what I remember it was mapperImpl being generated using generic param names for some reason i.e. param1, param2 vs myListMap, keyParent